# Justify Why Boundary Layer Exists at x=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

[image]

With part a of this question (I asked about latter parts before), does it suffice to find the outer solution and show that since both boundary conditions cannot be met, then there exists a boundary layer? How does this tell us that the BL is at 0 and not 1?

Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797146/finding-composite-solution and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546644/find-location-and-width-of-boundary-layer

Comment: Also this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533481/boundary-value-problem-with-rescaling/1534807#1534807